# SKLabelNode, can't use "SFMono-Light" as font

Tags: fonts, sprite-kit, sknode, sklabelnode

im try to use the font "SFMono-Light" as font of my SKlabel.. but keep getting the error says "SKLabelNode: SFMono-Light" font not found.

```
  func loadSKscene()->SKScene{ // load screenPFD
        let loadedScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "/Asset.scnassets/Korry.sks")!
        loadedScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        let skLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "ON")
        skLabel.fontColor = .white
        skLabel.fontSize = 35
        skLabel.fontName = "SFMono-Light"
        skLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
        skLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
        skLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 29)
        skLabel.zPosition = 1
        skLabel.name = "firstLineText"
        loadedScene.addChild(skLabel)
        
        //Test to find the children font
        print(loadedScene.children)
        

        return loadedScene
    }
```

Funny story, if from the editor I manually insert a SKlabelNode with font SFMono that's work fine ...

See the print out of my test:

[image: pic]

what I'm doing wrong..? why from editor I can set the Font and from code I can't..
Thanks

Comment: Do other font names, such as `SFMono`, work as the font name? The `-Light` part could be causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

First, for both the SF and SF Mono font, you must refer them by the family name, `SF` and `SF Mono`. And you can not add the weight suffix to them.

However that means you can't set the font weight. Instead, you could use an `AttributeString` for `SKLabelNode`:

```swift
let skLabel = SKLabelNode()
skLabel.attributedText = .init(
    string: "Score: 0", 
    attributes: [
        .font: NSFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 35, weight: .light)
    ])
```